# SQL - Copy row from one table to another and update column in destination table at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, copy

I have 2 tables like below structure. Both are identical except of table name.

```
tbl_item_color_exp
>>item_color_ID
>>color_ID
>>item_ID

tbl_item_color_live
>>item_color_ID
>>color_ID
>>item_ID
```

I wished to copy several rows from tbl_item_color_live table to tbl_item_color_exp table. I can accomplished copying the exact column and row by the following SQL below:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_item_color_exp 
SELECT * FROM tbl_item_color_live WHERE item_ID = $oldID
```

But I don't want to create replicate `item_color_ID` primary key and  I want to update all rows copied's item_ID column to a new variable, `$newID`. The general idea is copy all rows based on `$oldID` and update destination table with `&newID` but maintaining `color_ID` column with a auto incremented primary key `item_color_ID`.

I can accomplish it using several SQL queries but I was wondering if it is possible for me to do everything in more efficient manner by just one SQL line? I hope my question can be understandable by all, thank you.

Comment: @gbn : I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want, but it sounds like you only actually want to copy the `color_id`s, you want to set them all with a new `item_id`, and you want autonumbering to occur.

Sounds like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_item_color_exp (color_id,item_id)
SELECT color_id,$newID FROM tbl_item_color_live WHERE item_ID = $oldID
```

Comment: 18.5k - are you kidding me?  Lol.

Comment: Ops, you are right, the tables have switched role. My bad. Edited.

Comment: Wow, that worked, I didn't know I can use fixed variable value in SQL SELECT statement! Thanks. Btw, nice rating you have there, 18.5k!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_item_color_live (color_ID, item_ID)
SELECT color_ID, $newID FROM tbl_item_color_exp WHERE item_ID = $oldID
```